# Not able to enable https for my website in IIS 8 and Windows 2012 server

Tags: ssl, iis, https, iis-8, windows-server-2012

We have hosted a website in ASP.Net using IIS 8 and windows server 2012.

Has installed SSL from comodo. I have edited my bindings to have https with port 443 and selected the certificate.

Also, checked Firewall, and both port HTTP:80 and HTTPS:443 is enabled for all Public and Private

The website is working http, but not working in https. Also, if I do the same with default website, it works as localhost, but on a specific domain..

Comment: When you edited your bindings, did you select the right IP for the site? Or does your server only have 1 ip?

Comment: My server have only one IP.. and i have selected that. I have selected the same IP for http and its working.., but its not working for https

Answer (score 0):

If there is another SSL site on the same IP, then you may need to specify the hostname as well as ticking the 'require site indication' box under the SSL hostname